# Dynamic SQL - Update Column by Prepending A Current Column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to populate a column that is to represent an Internal URL that directs the user to a specific document. The document ID, `DOC_ID`, is already populated in the Table. I would like to populate the column by prepending a base URL to the Document ID. I do not know how to to do this dynamically and am getting some errors referring to the parameters of `CONCAT()`, issue being it is understanding it to be a string rather than the column value. My code is as follows:

```
SET @Insert_DRS_URL_SQL = 'UPDATE' 
                          + ' ' 
                          + QUOTENAME(@TBL) 
                          + ' ' 
                          + 'SET DRS_URL = CONCAT(@URLBASE' 
                          + ',' 
                          + 'DOC_ID' 
                          + ')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Insert_DRS_URL_SQL;
```

**UPDATE**

```
@URLBASE = 'http://blah/blah/blah/id='
```

`DRS_URL` is the column I wish to populate.

Basically I need `DRS_URL` = `@BASEURL` + `DOC_ID`

Comment: Where is `@URLBASE` set?

Comment: Do you really have documents stored in a bunch of tables? The reason you are having a problem is because you are using dynamic sql with what appears to be a parameter but you did not supply that parameter to your dynamic sql execution.

Comment: See Update above

Comment: `'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@tbl) + ' SET DRS_URL = CONCAT(''' + @URLBASE + ''', DOC_ID);`? If you need to parameterise the @URLBase (because you're worried about SQL injection) then you add the @URLBASE as a parameter to the sp_executesql part. Alternatively, you could just alter the tables that need it to have a computed column if the URL for everything in those tables is going to be exactly the same... That seems like a more sensible solution than this dynamic stuff, because when you add a value it will automatically have that URL.

Comment: (BTW, the proper way to parameterise your dynamic SQL would be like `EXEC sp_executesql @Insert_DRS_URL_SQL, N'@URLBASE NVARCHAR(255)', @URLBASE;` or something like that, but seeing as your @TBL would still be vulnerable to SQL injection, I'm not sure how much of an issue you think SQL injection is here).